# How can I fix a ValueError with maxPooling and convolution layers in Keras?

Tags: python-3.x, keras-layer

```
_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(512, 384, 3))
conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1024, kernel_size=(512, 384), strides=(32, 32),activation=tf.nn.relu)(_input)
#until here it works fine

maxPooling = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(64, 48), 
    strides=(16, 12), activation=tf.nn.relu)(maxPooling)
avrePooling = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(8, 8))(conv2)
conv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(64, 64),
    strides=(16, 16), activation=tf.nn.relu)(avrePooling)
flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(conv3)
dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu)(flatten)
dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)(dense1)
dense3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu)(dense2)
dense4 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu)(dense3)
_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(trainY.shape[1], activation=tf.nn.relu)(dense4) #trainY.shape[1] = 3
```

After the conv1 layer I get this error:

> ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'max_pooling2d/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,1,1,1024].
>   And when I delete that line, in the next line the same error appears again.

Comment: One of your dimensions has a size of 1 and you're trying to max pool it. Change your pools size from (2,2) to (1,1) since you're convolution leaves you with a 1x1 image.

Comment: Your convolution2d is the problem actually. It is the same size as your image. Either change the padding, or make the convolution kernel a size that is useful. ie not the size of the whole image.